# Function composition dynamically

Tags: scala, function-composition

Let' s say I have a function `move`.

Now, depending on some inputs (let' s say the input says "Move by 3"), I have to move 3 times.

I would do this like :

```
move compose move compose move
```

Is it possible to do function composition dynamically? So that I can build my new function depending on the number of times I have to move.

Thank you

Comment: Not written, but composed

Comment: Assuming `move` looks something like `move(Thing): Thing`, this is an example of an endofunctor (function from `a -> a` for some `a`) which is a monoid under function composition and the identity function. As shown in the answers, endofunctors can be composed as many times as necessary. In Haskell we'd write the desired function as `\n -> mconcat (replicate n move)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `Function.chain` method :

```
scala> val move1 = (x:Int) => x+1
move1: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val move5 = Function.chain(List.fill(5)(move1))
move5: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> move5(5)
res1: Int = 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use a fold:

```
def move(x: Int): Int = x + 1

def moveBy(n: Int) = 
  (1 to n).foldLeft[Int => Int](identity _) { (f, _) => f compose move }

moveBy(5)(0) // > 5
```